# Script sometimes work, sometimes not?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have created a script which lists the contents of a Google Drive location however I receive notifications of failures. Please note that I do not always receive failure notifications, and I cannot recreate the issue reliably.

```
// Expose contents of Drive to File Cabinet URL
function showFolderInSite() {
var folders = DocsList.getFolderById("FOLDERID").getFolders();
var files = DocsList.getFolderById("FOLDERID").getFiles();
var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("LINKTOFILECABINET");
var attachments = page.getAttachments();

// Remove dups
for(i in attachments){
attachments[i].deleteAttachment();
} 
// Iterate files
for(i in files){
page.addWebAttachment(files[i].getName(), '', files[i].getUrl());
}
// Iterate folders
for(i in folders){
page.addWebAttachment(folders[i].getName(), '', folders[i].getUrl());
} 
}
```

Comment: what kind of error/wrong behavior does your script produce?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah man, that happened to me too, i couldn't figure out why, i had to change the way i wrote the app And insert it as a gadget on my site!